# Why my .obj model is not showing?

Tags: html, aframe

I loaded .obj file. I saw in console it's loaded. Console is showing `OBJLoader: 271.079833984375ms` but I can't see the model. It's not showing. I faced this problem many times. I checked with `scale and position` but nothing is showing.

Comment: did you add the .mtl file ? can you upload the model somewhere (like glitch ?)